# ruby 1.9: how do I get a byte-index-based slice of a String?

Tags: ruby, string, unicode, ruby-1.9, multibyte

I'm working with UTF-8 strings. I need to get a slice using byte-based indexes, not char-based.

I found references on the web to `String#subseq`, which is supposed to be like `String#[]`, but for bytes. Alas, it seems not to have made it to 1.9.1.

Now, why would I want to do that? There's a chance I'll end up with an invalid string should I slice in the middle of a multi-byte char. This sounds like a terrible idea.

Well, I'm working with `StringScanner`, and it turns out its internal pointers are byte-based. I accept other options here.

Here's what I'm working with right now, but it's rather verbose:

```
s.dup.force_encoding("ASCII-8BIT")[ix...pos].force_encoding("UTF-8")
```

Both `ix` and `pos` come from `StringScanner`, so are byte-based.

Comment: Your solution is fine, if you accept the risk that the second force_encoding will raise an exception if you slice a multibyte string. There is a reason why doing stuff like this is hard.

Comment: Ruby 1.9.3 has String#byteslice.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this too: `s.bytes.to_a[ix...pos].join("")`, but that looks even more esoteric to me.

If you're calling the line several times, a nicer way to do it could be this:

```
class String
  def byteslice(*args)
    self.dup.force_encoding("ASCII-8BIT").slice(*args).force_encoding("UTF-8")
  end
end

s.byteslice(ix...pos)
```

Comment: This is just stashing away the same code. I was wondering if there is not indeed a char slicer in ruby19.

Comment: Sorry, but you seem to be a bit ambigual(?) here, do you want a char slicer or a byte slicer? As per ruby 1.9.1, there is no byte slicer without a bit of hacking. I personally like the first code in my answer the best, but that's up to you to choose.

Comment: I guess there isn't. Sometimes you have to add your own special use case to the Ruby standard library, and that's why the whole idea of open classes was invented.

Comment: As foro your first solution, it reads prettier, and I'm generally all for that, but this particular line runs a million times, so I'll go with the one that performs best. And that's also why I'm particularly interested in ruby having its own internal implementation, because then it'd probably be in C in the base string code.

Comment: Since #dup has already been called on the original string it might be nicer to call #slice! (rather than #slice) on the result to avoid creation of yet another object?

Answer (score 1):

Doesn't String#bytes do what you want? It returns an enumerator to the bytes in a string (as numbers, since they might not be valid characters, as you pointed out)

```
str.bytes.to_a.slice(...)
```

Comment: But I still need a substring, not an array of characters. It seems your suggestion would only make the operation a lot more expansive with going from enum to array and then making a utf8 string out of that again.

Comment: Array#pack and String#unpack can simplify that:

`your_string.unpack('C*').slice(...).pack('C*')`

Answer (score 1):

Use this monkeypatch until `String#byteslice()` is [added to Ruby 1.9](http://bugs.ruby-lang.org/issues/4447).

```
class String
  unless method_defined? :byteslice
    ##
    # Does the same thing as String#slice but
    # operates on bytes instead of characters.
    #
    def byteslice(*args)
      unpack('C*').slice(*args).pack('C*')
    end
  end
end
```